# bundle exec puma Error in Jelastic CMD / Entry Point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundle, jelastic

I have a docker image that contains a Ruby on Rails application and uses a Puma server.

I run into the following problem ...

When I deploy image in **Jelastic** with **bundle exec puma** command in
**CMD / Entry Point** the run.log file shows me the following error:

```
bundler error: command not found: puma 
Install missing gem executables with bundle install
```

But if I connect by ssh to the docker container and execute exactly the same command **bundle exec puma** (**whithout exec bundle install**) the puma server starts correctly.

In the Gemfile file and Gemfile.lock I have the puma gem.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1
WORKDIR /root/app
##### throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle config set deployment 'true'
RUN bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'
RUN bundle config set without 'development:test'
RUN bundle install -j4
COPY . .
RUN rake assets:precompile
CMD sh bin/web
```

**bin/web:**

```
bundle exec puma
```

any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Is Puma in fact listed in your `Gemfile`?  How are you starting the container, both in the cases where it does and doesn't work?  (Is a bind mount hiding the contents of the image's `vendor` tree?)

Comment: Not sure about a solution, but this looks suspiciously similar to a PATH or environment issue that you might face running a command manually vs. via cron.

Comment: Could you please provide these cases for deeper investigation:
1. Link regarding the platform where you have created environment
2. Name or appid of your environment
3. And link regarding custom docker image which you have used from DockerHub